# compare two decimal values with specific range in perl

Tags: perl, decimal

I am new to Perl. I have two different sets of arrays. Those two arrays having decimal values, both does not have an exact matches, it might be differ only either `+0.5` or `-0.5`. I tried this program, it's not working.

```
@inpt = qw(1003.3965 1036.4392 1037.3843 1045.4459 1101.4259 1107.4253 1118.3928 1191.4904 1320.4855 1420.6291 1440.6921 1562.6698 1742.7587 2084.9137 2248.8761 2337.8865 2628.9931);
@outpt = qw(1191.6017 1101.5336 2629.2865 1742.9336 1036.5726 2338.1574 2249.1057 1440.8222 1440.2074);

foreach $s (@outpt){

    $inc = $s + 0.5;
    $dec = $s - 0.5;

   foreach $p ( @inpt ) {
        if ( $p .. $inc ) {           
            print "$p \t $inc";
        }
        elsif ( $p .. $dec ) {
            print "$p \t $dec";
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the below output. The `@outpt` value of `1191.6017` is matching with the range of `+0.5` or `-0.5` in `@inpt` value of `1191.4904`.

```
outpt          inpt
1191.6017     1191.4904
1101.5336     1101.4259
2629.2865     2628.9931
1742.9336     1742.7587
1036.5726     1037.3843
2338.1574     2337.8865
2249.1057     2248.8761
1440.8222     1440.6291
1440.2074     1440.6291
```

Comment: the `..` operator doesn't do anything remotely like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $limit = 0.5;
my $result = "";

my @inpt = qw(1003.3965 1036.4392 1037.3843 1045.4459 1101.4259 1107.4253 1118.3928 1191.4904 1320.4855 1420.6291 1440.6921 1562.6698 1742.7587 2084.9137 2248.8761 2337.8865 2628.9931);
my @outpt = qw(1191.6017 1101.5336 2629.2865 1742.9336 1036.5726 2338.1574 2249.1057 1440.8222 1440.2074);

foreach my $s (@outpt){
   foreach my $t (@inpt) {
      if($s >= $t - $limit && $s <= $t + $limit) {
          $result .= "$s \t $t\n";
      }
   }
}     
print $result;
```

Comment: I want the output out of the loop. its possible.?

Answer (score 2):

```
my $limit = 0.5;

my @inpt = qw(1003.3965 1036.4392 1037.3843 1045.4459 1101.4259 1107.4253 1118.3928 1191.4904 1320.4855 1420.6291 1440.6921 1562.6698 1742.7587 2084.9137 2248.8761 2337.8865 2628.9931);
my @outpt = qw(1191.6017 1101.5336 2629.2865 1742.9336 1036.5726 2338.1574 2249.1057 1440.8222 1440.2074);

my @result = map {
  my $p = $_;
  map { "$p \t $_" } grep { abs($p-$_) <= $limit } @inpt;
  # without grep
  # map { abs($p-$_) <= $limit ? "$p \t $_" : () } @inpt;
} @outpt;

print $_, "\n" for @result;
```

output

```
1191.6017    1191.4904
1101.5336    1101.4259
2629.2865    2628.9931
1742.9336    1742.7587
1036.5726    1036.4392
2338.1574    2337.8865
2249.1057    2248.8761
1440.8222    1440.6921
1440.2074    1440.6921
```

Comment: Thank you.. Please can you explain the `map` function.

Answer (score 1):

The `nmin_by` function from the [`List::UtilsBy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy) is very useful for something like this. It allows you to find the value in a list that provides the smallest value when a given function is applied to it. If I use the *absolute difference* from the current element of `@outpt` then I can find the closest number in the `@inpt` list

It would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::UtilsBy 'nmin_by';

my @inpt = (
  1003.3965, 1036.4392, 1037.3843, 1045.4459, 1101.4259,
  1107.4253, 1118.3928, 1191.4904, 1320.4855, 1420.6291,
  1440.6921, 1562.6698, 1742.7587, 2084.9137, 2248.8761,
  2337.8865, 2628.9931,
);
my @outpt = (
  1191.6017, 1101.5336, 2629.2865, 1742.9336, 1036.5726,
  2338.1574, 2249.1057, 1440.8222, 1440.2074,
);

printf "%-9s      %-9s\n", qw/ outpt inpt /;

for my $out ( @outpt ) {
  my $inp = nmin_by { abs($out - $_) } @inpt;
  printf "%9.4f      %9.4f\n", $out, $inp;
}
```

**output**

```
outpt          inpt     
1191.6017      1191.4904
1101.5336      1101.4259
2629.2865      2628.9931
1742.9336      1742.7587
1036.5726      1036.4392
2338.1574      2337.8865
2249.1057      2248.8761
1440.8222      1440.6921
1440.2074      1440.6921
```

Comment: @Krithi.S: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: The same result i want to get out of the loop.. Now i tried and got it. Thank you..